# How can I embed private youtube video in my site?

Tags: video, youtube, private

I have to display some private Youtube videos in my blog. I cannot embed them directly. What should I use to do this.

Comment: You can't do this directly from YouTube, that's why they're "private".

Comment: If they're embeddable, then they can't exactly be private anymore...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this.  Private just means they won't show up in searches, but people with the private URL can still access them.  Blogs such as WordPress.com won't let you use the `<embed>` tag, so you'd have to use your own blog software or upload the video to a service such as VideoPress.

Comment: You should make them public ;). You can however, embed an _unlisted_ video - one which doesn't turn up on searches but doesn't need an invited account to view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, it belongs somewhere like [WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can embed private youtube videos on your site and even if you do, they will not be able to view it because it's private.

Comment: I believe you _can_ embed private videos. However the user needs to be logged in to Google and be granted access to the video. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177

Comment: This accepted answer is not correct anymore. I just tried uploading a private video, and was able to embed it and play it so long I am logged into my own Google account. So, it's possible.

Answer (score 111):

You should set your videos to "unlisted" instead of "private". That way the video does not show up on your channel or on any search results but anyone with a link to the video can see it and you can embed the video on any site.

Comment: This would allow the user to send the link to people the owner does not wish for them to see.

Comment: Yeah. I also need to implement the same functionality. Is there any way to restrict user from finding the URL.  I would be embedding the url in my website.

Comment: This use case (private and unlisted video, that can be shown ONLY on my web site) is one addressed with Vimeo.  For example, https://player.vimeo.com/video/233679054 is a video that we show on the logged in portion of our site, that anyone who is logged in to our site can view, but if they send the link to someone else, it will not play from the link.

Answer (score 11):

I didn't try this workaround yet but theoritcally it should work, you need to use YouTube API V 3 and follow the below steps:

1. Set the video's privacy status to unlisted through API.
2. Embed the video via API in a hidden div.
3. Use onPlayerStateChange event to check if the video player is currently playing the video, use the API to pause the video at the first second.
4. If the state changed to "playing" then send an AJAX request to a server side script to revert the the video's privacy status to be private, once you get a confirmation message display the video and use the API to
   play it.

This should keep the video private even if the user copy & paste the URL in another tab, s/he should get a message that the video is private.

[Here is a reference to YouTube iFrame API, which gives you an example for onPlayerStateChange Event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en)

[Please refer to this link to change the privacy status via API v 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235503/php-how-to-change-privacy-status-of-a-youtube-video-through-youtube-api-v3)

Comment: Good idea but this way will be facing with quota limit?

Comment: @HoangMinhDung I think the quota limit is not applied in such a scenario.

Comment: Do you think when updating video's privacy status won't cost any quota? 
I think it will according to this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost
and we can easily estimate the quota we gonna spend per day

Comment: @HoangMinhDung I'm not sure, I haven't tried this before, anyways you can always send a request to YouTube to raise your quota.

Comment: Youtube API has a default quota allocation of 10000 units per day. Since the video update quota cost is 50, you can only do this 10000/50 = 200 times per day. Therefore this is not a practical solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can embed your private videos but they will only show to you and those with whom you have shared it. See https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177 for more.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot embed private video to your website because it's private, so cannot show to public viewer in your website.
Until now Youtube has three licences: 
1 - Public: your video can be viewed publicly
2 - Unlisted: your video can seen or embedded by url or link and not show up in search result or your channel
3 - Private: your video is private, cannot be viewed

Answer (score 2):

Came across this issue in 2023 and it seems like other alternatives like Vimeo are a better solution to a case where private video needs to be embedded onto a page. I am dealing with a custom web application which shows videos under a course that has been bought and was expecting that YouTube would serve as a hosting platform and videos could be retrieved by their ID's.

I tried many different things and even though "unlisted" videos serve as part of the solution, I encourage using Vimeo as it provides extra features, although it is paid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can embed private and unlisted files on your website. If private, Youtube will ask for a login (if there is none) and the credentials will give access to watch the content or not, based on you are a manager/admin of the channel or have an invitation (invite emails from dashboard).

If unlisted it will show!

The video must be embeddable!