# How can I link my private videos on YouTube to be played on my website?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can I link my private videos on YouTube to be played on my website. The point is to bring more viewers to my site by making videos available on my site, yet private on YouTube.

Comment: Not possible. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16936519/542564

Answer (score 0):

> You should set your videos to "unlisted" instead of "private". That
>   way the video does not show up on your channel or on any search
>   results but anyone with a link to the video can see it and you can
>   embed the video on any site.

I didn't try this workaround yet but theoretically it should work, you need to use YouTube API V 3 and follow the below steps:

Set the video's privacy status to unlisted through API.
Embed the video via API in a hidden div.
Use onPlayerStateChange event to check if the video player is currently playing the video, use the API to pause the video at the first second.
If the state changed to "playing" then send an AJAX request to a server side script to revert the the video's privacy status to be private, once you get a confirmation message display the video and use the API to play it.
This should keep the video private even if the user copy & paste the URL in another tab, s/he should get a message that the video is private.

References:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

[PHP - How to change privacy status of a youtube video through Youtube API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235503/php-how-to-change-privacy-status-of-a-youtube-video-through-youtube-api-v3)