# PHP - How to change privacy status of a youtube video through Youtube API v3?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I need to know how can I change the privacy status of a youtube video. The video have 'unlisted' privacy status and I want to change to 'public'.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=es#examples) there is an example to add some tags to video but i don't know how to apply the example for update privacy status. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have set the privacy status when uploading video to YouTube. I believe it similar for updating the video also.

I didn't test the following code. But I hope you can give a shot.

First you retrieve the video status property.

```
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('status', array('id' => $videoId));
```

Then you get the video status property

```
$video = $listResponse[0];
$videoStatus = $video['status'];
```

Then you set the video status. Valid values are 'private', 'public', 'unlisted'.

```
$videoStatus->privacyStatus = 'public';
```

Finally you update the status & then video

```
$video->setStatus($videoStatus);
$updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update('status', $video);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Could you to help doing the same but changing the privacy status of a playlist ?

Comment: Its similar to the answer. Following are the changes you have to make. 1 - Retrieval of playlist `$youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('status', array('id' => $playlistId));`. 2 - Update of playlist `$youtube->playlists->update('status', $playlistStatus);`. Settings the status is same. I never tried. Hope this also will help you.

Comment: `$youtube->playlists->listPlaylists('status,snippet', array('id' => $playlistId));`. 2 - Update of playlist `$youtube->playlists->update('status,snippet', $playlistStatus);` I need to put snippet because the request needs the snippet.title Now works perfect ;)

Comment: Can this be done without OAuth2 - and just by using the API key connected to the account that owns the video?